# Thunderbird only downloads email inside of folders, once I am looking at that folder

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird only downloads the emails from within my folders after I click on the folders and not before. So I basically never know if I have emails in there until I click on them.

It's using IMAP and it is setup to check for mail on startup and every 10 minutes after that.

Is this caused by the fact that I'm filtering emails and moving them to folders? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you using IMAP or POP3?  On the server settings for each account, is it set to check for mail every so many minutes?

Comment: Its IMAP and yes it is setup to check on startup and every 10 minutes after that.

Comment: Are you filtering in Thunderbird, or is Thunderbird getting messages from an email service with a web mail interface (like gmail or Yahoo), and you have the filtering set up there?  Mail in the inbox on the server is generally downloaded periodically.  But if you immediately move the messages to other folders on the server, those other folders may not be synced until you click on them in Thunderbird.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have mixed results with this. Usually, the filtered messages get downloaded into the new subfolders right away, but not always. I'm on Linux, but I don't know if that makes a difference in this case since it's really all IMAP magic on my ISP's server.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option for that, but you need to enable this for every folder:

- right-click the folder
- mark the check box "When getting new messages for this account, always check this folder"

I assume that this is disabled by default for performance reasons.